# Gem install looking for mapped drive

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rake

On the network my home folder is set as a mapped drive assigned the letter H.  When executing "gem install rake" gets an error that H can't be found.  The drive is mapped as H:.  I see the .gems folder in that folder while the ruby install is in the root of c:.  What do I need to change to have the ability to install gems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing this is not the best solution, but I modified gem.bat in my ruby>bin folder. I wrapped the existing command with:

```
SET _HOMEDIRECTORY=%HOMEDIRECTORY%
SET HOMEDIRECTORY=C:
[existing code]
SET HOMEDIRECTORY=%_HOMEDIRECTORY%
```

This changes the environment variable of the home directory from H: to C:, installs, then returns it back to H:.

I got the idea from this thread: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/207694